# Aframe testing environment setup for my local project

Tags: testing, aframe

I need to set up a frame's testing env to my local project. Does anyone know the step to set it up?

What I mean by testing env is that installing *karma, mocha, chai, sinon* npm dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Getting testing to work was such a nightmare for me as a brand new js dev. Here's my answer derived from hours upon hours of trial and error

`npm install --save-dev chai@^4.1.2 karma@^1.7.1 karma-browserify@^5.1.1 karma-chrome-launcher@^2.2.0 karma-firefox-launcher@^1.0.1 karma-mocha@^1.3.0 karma-mocha-reporter@2.1.0 karma-sinon-chai@^1.3.2 mocha@^3.5.3 sinon@^2.1.0 sinon-chai@^2.13.0`